# Adding grid.lines to tkinter doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wrote a script, that shows how many days certain food items are opened.  It is displayed on an lcd via tkinter. However, when i add a new item, no 7th  row is added. One item is overwritten.
Where could my mistake be?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import datetime
from tkinter import *


food = {'potatoes': datetime.date(2018, 12, 8),'sausage': datetime.date(2018, 12, 12), 'cream': datetime.date(2018, 12, 13), 'cauliflower': datetime.date(2018, 12, 11), 'ham': datetime.date(2018, 12, 10)}
food_count = len(food.items())



def add():
    food["tomato"] = datetime.date.today()
    food_count = len(food.items())
    show()


def show():    
    for i in range(0, int(food_count)):
        name, date = list(food.items())[i]
        days_open = (datetime.date.today() - date).days
        label_name = Label(master=window, width=width, height=height,
                                          font=("Arial",10),
                                           text = name)
        label_days= Label(master=window, width=width, height=height,
                                          font=("Arial",10),
                                           text = days_open)
        label_name.grid(row=i+1,column=1)
        label_days.grid(row=i+1,column=2)

width = 20
height = 2

window = Tk()
window.geometry('480x320')

button_add = Button(master=window, width=width, height=height,
                text="Add",
                command=add,
                font=("Arial",10))

label_01 = Label(master=window, width=width, height=height,
              font=("Arial",10),
              text = "Lebensmittel")

label_02 = Label(master=window, width=width, height=height,
              font=("Arial",10),
              text = "geöffnet seit")

button_add.grid(row=0,column=0)
label_01.grid(row=0,column=1)
label_02.grid(row=0,column=2)

show()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I took your script and added 10 more items to your list of foods. When I ran the code, the tkinter window looked as expected. 15 rows of foods with no overwrites. This means that the error is in your add() function.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have an answer:
your code is:

```
def add():
    food["tomato"] = datetime.date.today()
    food_count = len(food.items())
    show()


def show():

for i in range(0, int(food_count)):
    name, date = list(food.items())[i]
    days_open = (datetime.date.today() - date).days
    label_name = Label(master=window, width=width, height=height,
                                      font=("Arial",10),
                                       text = name)


    label_days= Label(master=window, width=width, height=height,
                                      font=("Arial",10),
                                       text = days_open)


    label_name.grid(row=i+1,column=1)
    label_days.grid(row=i+1,column=2)
```

but in def show() the for loop does not do anything because food_count is not defined in it, so the for lop does not do anything,
see if this works

```
def add():
    food["tomato"] = datetime.date.today()
    #food_cound moved to def show
    show()


def show():
    food_count = len(food.items())
    for i in range(0, int(food_count)):
        name, date = list(food.items())[i]
        days_open = (datetime.date.today() - date).days
        label_name = Label(master=window, width=width, height=height,
                                          font=("Arial",10),
                                           text = name)


        label_days= Label(master=window, width=width, height=height,
                                          font=("Arial",10),
                                           text = days_open)


        label_name.grid(row=i+1,column=1)
        label_days.grid(row=i+1,column=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this code is the line:

```
food_count = len(food.items())
```

This line creates a new variable in the local scope, but does not change the variable in the global scope (see [local vs global scope](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php)).

To fix this, you need to change the `add` function to:

```
def add():
    global food_count
    food["tomato"] = datetime.date.today()
    food_count = len(food.items())
    show()
```

This will make sure that `food_count` is in the global scope.